# How to define [bigint] in powershell windows7?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

We are unable to define data type `[bigint]` in powershell version 2 in OS win7, also we use `[System.Numerics.BigInteger]` again not work,

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) structure is introduced with `.net 4.0`. What version are you using? What does `$PSVersionTable` return?

Comment: I have powershell version 2 in win, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/803034fa2d0d241cce408370d61ada29

Comment: What does `$PSVersionTable` return? You can [enable .net 4.0](https://learn-powershell.net/2012/01/10/enable-net-4-0-access-from-powershell-v2/)  using Powershell V.2 apparently

Comment: did you read my comment or did you get it resolved?

Comment: Yes, but not resolve it,

Comment: What didn't resolve it? Using `.net 4.0`? Are you using `.net 4.0` and for the last time before I give up: what does `$PSVersiontable` return?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately PowerShell version 2 doesn't support this. But in 3.O and later versions you can achieve this.

```
[bigint]1e20
```

It will give following output:

```
100000000000000000000
```

Comment: As you said you are using PowerShell version 2 it will not work here. because it doesn't support this feature.

Comment: Yeah i know, this means any solution for it? my means i can define manually bigint type in powershell?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am not aware of it. As of now what i can suggest is to upgrade your PowerShell version. Later if I find any information regarding this I'll let you know.